# Python join element i with i+1

Tags: python

I have a list of dates

```
dates = [date1, date2, date3, date4, ...]
```

where each date is of the form '2010-01-01' for example

and I want to create an array:

```
ranges = [date1+'-'+date2, date2+'-'+date3, date3+'-'+date4,...]
```

I can get this with a for loop that throws up an error:

```
ranges = []
for i, t in enumerate(result): 
    ranges.append(t+"-"+result[i+1])
```

which obviously crashes out at the final i because I am referencing i+1. I can't think how to do this neatly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my_ranges = []
for i range(len(dates)-1): #go til the second to last element
    my_ranges.append(dates[i] + "-" + dates[i+1])
```

Or if you want to do it in one line with a list comprehension:

```
my_ranges = ["-".join( (dates[i],dates[i+1])) for i in range(len(dates)-1)]
```

And even shorter with the zip and map.

```
map("-".join, zip(dates, dates[1:]))
```

Comment: That's really not Pythonic. You'd prefer to do `for i, t in enumerate(result[:-1]):`, but even then I'd rather iterate on `zip(result, result[1:])` instead.

Comment: Sometimes you shouldn't look like a try-hard for pythonic solution. ;)

Comment: @martijnn2008: And this time is not one of them. No reason to go for this instead of something much simpler to read.

Comment: So you think the solution below is easier to read? This solution exactly says what's happening.

Comment: @martijnn2008: Using common, known patterns is indeed a great solution for writing readable code. Though in this case, if `pairwise` was only used once, I'd rather do `[date + next_date for date, next_date in zip(result, result[1:])]`. To be honest, I don't really care what solution OP uses, but this answer is not Pythonic code and I think it deserves a comment saying so. Most of the time, if you see a `range(len(seq))`, it's better to replace it with `enumerate` and this case is no exception.

Comment: Thanks guys, I really like the map and zip method. I didn't know about those functions.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [pairwise](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) recipe:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

Demo:

```
In [77]: dates =["date1", "date2", "date3", "date4"]

In [78]: from itertools import izip, tee

In [79]: map("-".join, pairwise(dates))
Out[79]: ['date1-date2', 'date2-date3', 'date3-date4']
```

for python3 replace izip with zip:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```

And call list on map if you want to get a list or use a list comp:

```
In [5]: from itertools import  tee

In [6]: list(map("-".join, pairwise(dates)))
Out[6]: ['date1-date2', 'date2-date3', 'date3-date4']
```

Or roll your own:

```
def pairs(l):
    it = iter(l)
    prev = next(it)
    for ele in it:
        yield "{}-{}".format(prev, ele)
        prev = ele
```

Demo:

```
In [10]: list(pairs(dates))
Out[10]: ['date1-date2', 'date2-date3', 'date3-date4']
```

All the approaches avoid indexing or making extra copies of the data.

You can also use `enumerate` checking the index:

```
print(["{}-{}".format(dte,dates[i]) for i, dte in enumerate(dates, 1) if i < len(dates)])
```

Which gives you the same:

```
['date1-date2', 'date2-date3', 'date3-date4']
```